# Inserting path of a image into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Here is my controller insertion code**
This code inserts image into image path folder but the path is not saving in database.

```
function add_hotel() {
      //validate form input
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelname', 'Hotel Name', 'required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotellocation', 'Hotel Location', 'required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelphone', 'Hotel Phone', 'required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelimg', 'Hotel Image ', 'callback__image_upload');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('hotelabout', 'Hotel About', 'required|xss_clean');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
      {     

         $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
         $config['max_size']    = '1000000';
         $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
         $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
         $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $field_name = "hotelimg";
         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
                {
         $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

         $this->load->view('admin/add_hotel', $error);
                    }
    else {

        $data = array(
            'hotelname'             => $this->input->post('hotelname'),
            'hotellocation'     => $this->input->post('hotellocation'),
            'hotelphone'            => $this->input->post('hotelphone'),
            'hotelimg'      =>    $this->upload->data('hotelimg'),
            'hotelabout'            => $this->input->post('hotelabout')
                );
            print_r($data);

            $this->db->insert('hotel_content', $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Hotel added successfully.</p>");

            redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/hotel_controller/index');
                }
```

Error shown is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Array to string conversion
>       Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>       Line Number: 552

and

A Database Error Occurred:

> Error Number: 1054
>       Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
>       INSERT INTO `hotel_content` (`hotelname`, `hotellocation`, `hotelphone`, `hotelimg`, `hotelabout`) VALUES ('hotel5', 'hyd', '0402365477', Array, 'welcome')
>       Filename: G:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\system\database\DB_driver.php
>       Line Number: 330

I need path to be inserted in database. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace else part with

```
else {

            $data = array(
                'hotelname'             => $this->input->post('hotelname'),
                'hotellocation'     => $this->input->post('hotellocation'),
                'hotelphone'            => $this->input->post('hotelphone'),
                'hotelimg'      =>    $this->upload->data('hotelimg'),
                'hotelabout'            => $this->input->post('hotelabout')
            );
            print_r($data);

            $this->db->insert('hotel_content', $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Hotel added successfully.</p>");

            redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/hotel_controller/index');
            }
```

with this

```
else {
            $image_path = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
                'hotelname'                => $this->input->post('hotelname'),
                'hotellocation'        => $this->input->post('hotellocation'),
                'hotelphone'             => $this->input->post('hotelphone'),
                'hotelimg'      =>    $image_path[full_path],
                'hotelabout'              => $this->input->post('hotelabout')
            );
            print_r($data);

            $this->db->insert('hotel_content', $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Hotel added successfully.</p>");

            redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/hotel_controller/index');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the line "$this->upload->data('hotelimg')" in else part returns an array. 
You just need uploaded path from it which can be extracted as:

```
$temp = $this->upload->data('hotelimg');
$uploadedPath = $temp[full_path];
```